# Webview through option menu in android application

Tags: android, webview

I have been trying to open URL in webView when an option from the options menu gets selected. For simplicity, I am trying firstly if any of the options got selected, A passed hard-coded string passed to webView activity in "passedUrl". I am using putExtra() to pass URL to 'webViewShow' activity.

This is the code of first activity in which my options menu exists :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    String url = "http://kavishala.in/about-us";

    Intent webView = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InAppWebView.class);
    getIntent().putExtra("passedUrl",url);
    startActivity(webView);
    return true;
}
```

Now the 'webViewShow' activity's java code to which I am passing URL:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in_app_web_view);

    final String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("passedUrl");
    WebView window = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebWindow);
    window.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    window.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Where I am creating a WebView and loading that 'passedUrl' into it.

**Compilation and result:** The application gets successful built. Everything goes fine until I run the application and select an option from the options menu. It crashes after selection from the options menu. A blank screen appears after selection although, I think it suggests that the 'webViewShow' activity has been started but failed to load URL.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
  Intent webView = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InAppWebView.class);
  getIntent().putExtra("passedUrl",url);
  startActivity(webView);
```

To

```
  Intent webView = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InAppWebView.class);
  webView.putExtra("passedUrl",url);
  startActivity(webView);
```